# Wordpress theme language settings

Tags: wordpress, localization, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with the language of my wordpress theme.
I have a theme that have a folder "language" that contain some file.
Each file contain the text for the specific language.
I have set the English language in `wp-config.php`, but in the front-end, some phrases of the theme are not in English.

How can I fix this?

I can't understand why I see some phrases in another language, if I have set the `wp-config.php` for the en language.

There is another setting that I ignore?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between theme language and content language. The text you see in other language should be content of you site, i.e. something of which there is no available translation.

You can use content translation extensions.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: not really.I try to explane me better.
An example of a phrase is the 404 content.
In the various language files, there are also the phrases for 404 content,but i can see it in the language that i've set in wp-config.
This is what I mean.
Do you have understand now?
I hope :-)

Comment: Yes of course, it may be working with a standard wordpress theme/tempalate.
In custom templates, there may have been defined some text string as "not translatable" by adding them directly in code, instead of adding a text variable which should be retrived from language file.

This is also the same problem with others CMS' like Joomla and drupal

Comment: But the fact is that the specific phrase that i've mentioned (the content of the 404 page), is contained in the language file,is not written directly in the code.
This is the strange thing!